# JPanel scroll tabs won't appear

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I've created a JPanel with a JScrollPane and trying to use it scroll through randomly generated colors. The size of the randomly generated colored squares are 64px X 64px covering an area of 100 X 100 squares. So naturally, I would expect that since the area far exceeds the JPanel's area, the scrollbars would execute. But from the screenshot below, the scrollbar is not working properly with no scrollbar tabs.

[image]

*(extends JPanel)*

```
private void createCanvasWindow()
{
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    _scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this);
    _scrollPane.setViewportView(this);
    _scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    _scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    _scrollPane.setBounds(10, 10, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    _gen = new JButton("Gen");
    _gen.addActionListener(this);
    _gen.setBounds(16 + WIDTH, 10 + HEIGHT, 80, 32);
    _gen.setVisible(true);

    _frame.getContentPane().add(_gen);
    _frame.getContentPane().add(_scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Use one of [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: @Reimeus I got the same results. Code updated.

Comment: How do y determine the size of "this"? Given the fact tat you seem to be using null layout sever else, I would suggest you don't understand how component sizes are actually calculated

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not trying to scroll my JFrame if that is what you are implying, because my jscrollpane/jpanel is independent of it, and yes the frame layout is null. But are you suggesting that I add a layout to my JFrame and possibly an inner layout? My bigger concern is about how it might affect where something place and if it retains the shape and position that I want.

Comment: `_scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this);` <-- How is the size of `this` (and what is `this`) determined?

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: EDIT: The following assumes that these 100x100 squares are also components, and if this is not the case, the following is void: You're adding `this` to the scroll pane. And `this` is a panel that obviously has a `BorderLayout`. How should you arrange these sub-panels in a `BorderLayout`? Give it a `GridLayout`, and add these 100x100 sub-panels. Then it will automatically determine its size (no need to override `getPreferredSize` or so - the layout manager will take care of this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> _scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this);

Whatever component you add to the scrollpane will control the scrollbars. The scrollbars will appear when the preferred size of the component added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane. So whatever the "this" component is needs to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the component, since from what I can tell you are doing custom painting and each component is responsible for determining its own preferred size.

Comment: The component for "this" was a JPanel. Seems that a lot of people missed the part where I typed (extends JPanel). But you were right about getPreferredSize().